# Importing External jar Causes Issue

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have used this command to push my jar to maven repository.(created jar using mvn clean install)

> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=abc-model-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -DgroupId=com.abc -DartifactId=abc-model -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true

After successfully adding the jar to local mvn repository I have added the following as the dependency where I am going to use it.

```
 <dependency>
       <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
       <artifactId>abc-model</artifactId>
       <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </dependency>
```

But I am unable to access packages inside the jar. And also it is not in the External Libraries also. 
I have some model classes that I am trying to do is use those in a different project.

Comment: Please show us the error you get when you build, e.g. with `mvn clean verify`.

Comment: There is no error with that. My dependency is not loaded to External Libraries.

Comment: If you can build with `mvn clean install` without error, then all necessary libraries are there. It might be that Eclipse or IntelliJ don't show them, but that is another story.

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I have figure out the problem. This can be affected by 2 ways.

1. I have used the IntelliJ terminal to build the project. But it didn't work. But when I use the CMD(terminal) it worked as expected.

and also

Previously I have used that dependency as follows. in Scope Compile is the default. But after I adding the scope only it worked as expected. I cannot say the exact reason for this.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.abc.models</groupId>
        <artifactId>abc-model</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Forgot to give the scope. After adding Scope like this it worked.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.abc.models</groupId>
        <artifactId>abc-model</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: No, this what not the problem. If you do not specify a scope, the scope is automatically `compile`. I bet if you remove the scope, it still works.

Comment: And also use CMD(Terminal) rather than the IDE terminal will resolve this issue